# info.plist bundle display name localization

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, localization

There are a lot of posts on this but all seem to be an out of date method? It seems its done using info.plist and adding localization to it and then more info.plist files are created within for each language. It seems to be working but only ever displays the English Bundle display name no matter what system language I use. Not sure what else needs to be done. I checked it on both the simulator and a device.

[image]

Comment: There's no CFBundleDisplayName, there's only Bundle display name and Bundle name.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you need to create "InfoPlist.strings" and add languages which you want to support there, then set your bundle name and display name as the following for each language

```
"CFBundleDisplayName" = "App Name";
"CFBundleName" = "App Name";
```

How to enable Localization and add more language to your project.

1. [Choose your project on the tree.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jyeuz.png)
2. Choose your project.
3. Info Tab -> Localizations.
4. [Choose which language you want to support.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJpdV.png)

[then on your strings file, when you choose it, on right side you can find which languages you want to support into this strings file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuhrz.png)

Comment: So you don't enable localization on the file Info.plist?

Comment: logic here is kinda same like any key and value u set for localization, when u enable localization, app will search for those keys and set the value u provide to them , so it will search for CFBundleDisplayName and assign to it the value your provided

Comment: How do you assign language to each InfoPlist.strings? You have to set localization for it?

Comment: OK I tried it and yes you then add localization to the InfoPlist.strings and it works great! If you update your answer to include this step I'll accept it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: to add localizations to your project you 
1- Choose your project on the tree
2- Choose your project
3- Info Tab > Localizations
4- Choose which language you want to support.

then on your strings file, when you choose it, on right side you can find which languages you want to support into this strings file

i will add a screenshot to clarify it better